# How do I make each user's data separate when a new user sign up using Android Studio(java) Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, storing-data

I'm working on a project. I want to make each user's data separate from each other. I think I have a problem in saving and retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database.

I have two tables:

- "Users"

  - username, email, phone, password
- "Passwords"

  - accountType, username, email, phone, password

First user signs up and save their respective passwords/data and signs out from the system. And when second user signs up, the data of first user will not be visible to the second one.

**Here is saving the Passwords/data**

```
String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
        PasswordModel model = new PasswordModel(accountType, userName, email, phone, password);
        assert id != null;
        databaseReference.child(id).setValue(model);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textClear();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllPasswordsActivity.class));
```

**And here I'm setting the data to Recyclerview**

```
public void setData() {
    binding.recyclerViewPasswords.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PasswordModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PasswordModel>()
            .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("passwords"), PasswordModel.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new PasswordAdapter(options);
    binding.recyclerViewPasswords.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? Otherwise it's pretty hard for anyone to know what the issue is

Comment: Code is working. But the data is visible for all newly signed up users. I don't know exactly which code I shall share.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Code is working. There is no error. But the saved data was visible to all the new users. I was little bit confused about saving and reading data from Firebase. Now the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

**I've made some changes in saving the data**

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
        final String id = databaseReference.push().getKey(); // AUTO GENERATING ID
        final PasswordModel model = new PasswordModel(accountType, userName, email, phone, password);
        databaseReference.child(userId).child(id).setValue(model);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textClear();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllPasswordsActivity.class));
```

**And some changes in retrieving data**

```
public void setData() {
    binding.recyclerViewPasswords.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userId = firebaseUser.getUid();

    databaseReference.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {

                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PasswordModel> options =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PasswordModel>()
                                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("passwords").child(userId), PasswordModel.class)
                                .build();

                adapter = new PasswordAdapter(options);
                adapter.startListening();
                binding.recyclerViewPasswords.setAdapter(adapter);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AllPasswordsActivity.this, "No data available for this user, Save your data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

**The Problem resolved.**